# Accessing children of div and appending span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am accessing my children like this, i am trying to set the span title for the each div container.

```
$(".div-container").children().each(function(n, i){    
    console.log("Is it coming" + this.id);
    $(this.id).before($('<span />').css('margin-left' , '60px').attr({'class':'progress-title' }).html('Title'));
    $(this.id).before($('<span />').attr({'class':'progress-title-after' }).html('25% Usage'));
});
```

I am getting the corresponding the id's, but the span element is not getting added to my div containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not

```
$(this).before($('<span />').... // rest of code
```

instead of concatenating those IDs like

```
$(this.id).before($('<span />').... // rest of code
```

Because you're fetching IDs of each children so ultimately you're getting the object itself

Comment: I have something like this now. $("#progress-div :last-child").css('margin-right', 'auto'); In this place of progress-div how can i apply div.

Comment: @Shane You just have to write `div` like this: `$("div:last-child").css('margin-right', 'auto')`; But this will target `last-child`s for the context

Comment: Its targetting all the div's last child... but i want the current context childrens last div.

Comment: @Shane then you have to specify its context like `$("div:last-child", context)`!

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to the element, so you don't need to reselect it by ID. Just wrap `this` in a jQuery object.

```
$(this).before($('<span />').css('margin-left' , '60px').attr({'class':'progress-title' }).html('Title'));
```